# Google Guide to app architecture suspend function error

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am using google guide to build architecture(https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide) for my new android app. But when I am using Flow to return data from room database as mentioned above there is something unexpected :

```
   @HiltViewModel
   class CategoriesViewModel @Inject constructor(categoriesRepository:CategoriesRepository) : ViewModel() {
         var categories : LiveData<List<Category>> = 
             categoriesRepository.getCategories().asLiveData()
   }


   class CategoriesRepository @Inject constructor(val categoryDao: CategoryDao) {

   suspend fun getCategories(): Flow<List<Category>> {
       refreshCategories()
      // Returns a Flow object directly from the database.
      return categoryDao.getAll()
   }

   private suspend fun refreshCategories() {
      val response = ApiInterface.create().getCategories()
      categoryDao.insertAll(response.data!!)
   }
   }
```

The error is : Suspend function 'getCategories' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function.
But in the guide these functions are suspend functions.
How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling suspending `getCategories()` from non-suspending `CategoriesViewModel` constructor.

In the guide you linked, the constructor code wraps the suspending function call in

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    ...
}
```

Comment: when i am using viewModelScope in init method of viewmodel, viewModel.categories.observe in fragment returns nullPointer